# How to create XML with <![CDATA[<?xml in PL SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Let's suppose that I want to generate a part of the XML extracting data from a table and put this part inside the [CDATA element.

For example, let's suppose that I generate this XML

```
select    xmlelement("TAG1",
          xmlelement("TAG2",col2),
          xmlelement("TAG3",
          xmlelement("TAG4",col4)))
from MYTABLE
```

where col2 and col4 are columns of MYTABLE

so as to get the follow XML:

```
<TAG1>
 <TAG2> 10 </TAG2>
 <TAG3>
  <TAG4> England </TAG4>
 </TAG3>
</TAG1>
```

But now let's suppose I want to get something like this:

```
<TAG1>
 <TAG2> 10 </TAG2>
 <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <TAG3>
  <TAG4> England </TAG4>
 </TAG3> ]]>
</TAG1>
```

how can I do it?
What I mean is even in this case I want the part inside the CDATA to be created not with constant long string but alway extracting data from the table and I want this section closed after TAG3

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution,It's a hack with `REPLACE`.

For a fixed String :

```
select   REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlelement("TAG1",
          xmlelement("TAG2",col2),
           xmlelement("TAGX",
          xmlelement("TAG3",
          xmlelement("TAG4",col4)))),'/TAGX',']]'),'TAGX','![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?')
from MYTABLE;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TAG1>
   <TAG2>10</TAG2>
   <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><TAG3><TAG4>England</TAG4></TAG3>]]>
</TAG1>
```

Now use column value from `CDATA.MYTABLE.Col5` Column.The value is `StringtoInserttoCDATA.`

```
select   REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlelement("TAG1",
          xmlelement("TAG2",col2),
           xmlelement("TAGX",
          xmlelement("TAG3",
          xmlelement("TAG4",col4)))),'</TAGX',']]'),'TAGX','![CDATA[<?xml '||col5)
as xmldataStringInsertedfromcol
from MYTABLE;
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TAG1>
   <TAG2>10</TAG2>
   <![CDATA[<?xml StringtoInserttoCDATA><TAG3><TAG4>England</TAG4></TAG3>]]>
</TAG1>
```

Complete solution demo can be found in dbfiddlelink https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54dc5d9b1d4c8b2b08912925da59837c